# Hide socket.io traffic for client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Maybe a obvious question for all but not for me:)

Im using socket.io with redis and node.js, nginx.

My question is, is it possible to hide websocket traffic in browser? (if i use devtool traffic Ws)

Comment: What do you mean by 'hide websocket traffic in browser'? Just don't output anything to the browser?

Comment: No, you can't hide websocket traffic.